# Magento: Fetching selected value from Country dropdown in admin module

Tags: php, magento

I am creating an admin module in magento. As many tutorials suggest , I have added the country drop-down in my form. Now what should I do to fetch the selected value of that drop-down and display it in grid??  My drop-down is as follows in Form.php:

```
$fieldset->addField('country', 'select', 
                     array(
                'name'  => 'country',
                'label'     => 'Country',
                'values'    => Mage::getModel('adminhtml/system_config_source_country')->toOptionArray(),

     ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Helly, every things seems fine. Try to print Country Array Format. It should be like:

```
$fieldset->addField('country', 'select', array(
            'name'  => 'country',
            'label'     => 'Country',
            'values'    => array(
                              array(
                                  'value'     => 1,
                                  'label'     => 'Country 1',
                              ),

                              array(
                                  'value'     => 2,
                                  'label'     => 'Country 2',
                              ),
                            )
 ));
```

Hope will help!

Comment: thanks  i have already placed the drop-down. Now the question is, when user will ne selecting a value, how will i fetch it in my module???

Comment: In that case, any country will not selected in Country Dropdown.